# I need help migrating data through databases

Tags: sql-server-2008, migration

I have a web page with some data about the users. Recently, I made a complete change and start developing a new portal and of course a new DB structure. My question : What is the best way to migrate my data from my old DB to my new DB ? My old DB, and my new DB have similar but different structures, both are in SQL SERVER 2008 R2. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends on how different the various tables are.  Without knowing how different the tables are between the databases, I would probably expect a combination of scripts and data compare-import tools such as Red Gate's Data Compare tool.

Using Red Gate's Data Compare, you can work around minor differences in table structures.

For splitting tables or significant changes within a table, you may be better off writing an import script from a local copy of your old database or a live connection to the old database.